# Plot has no solid line when doing a multi-line plot out of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I got a dataframe with the following info:

```
date  time   percentage
 12   08:09      42    
 12   08:09      42    
 12   08:21      41    
 12   08:47      40    
 ...    ...         ...
 13   23:13      53    
 13   23:14      54    
 13   23:15      55    
 13   23:16      56
```

and i use the following code:

```
df.percentage=df.percentage.astype(int)

df.set_index([df.groupby(['date']).cumcount(), 'date', 'time'])['percentage']\
  .unstack('date').reset_index(0, drop=True).sort_index().plot()
```

If i run this code and plot one line out of one log file i get this result:

[image]

But when i use this in a log when there are two diffrent dates i get this:

[image]

But i want the get two solid lines, what do i wrong?

Comment: Hi Metroll, please provide a [mcve](/help/mcve).

Comment: done, hope you can help me

Comment: do you have a percentage for both days at any minute or there are missing ones?

Comment: there are missing ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening here is that in the first case the library is automatically interpolating the missing point while in the second this doesn't happen.

Let's reproduce your code:

```
# first we try to create df
    %matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dates = pd.date_range(start='2019-04-12 08:00',
                      end='2019-04-12 23:45',
                      freq="T")
df = pd.DataFrame({"date":dates})
df1 = (df["date"]+pd.DateOffset(1)).to_frame()
df = pd.concat([df,df1], ignore_index=True)

# Now we need to remove some (50%) rows
idx2rm =np.random.choice(range(len(df)),int(len(df)*.5) , replace=False)

df = df[~df.index.isin(idx2rm)].reset_index(drop=True)

df["time"] = df.date.astype(str).str[-8:-3]
df["date"] = df["date"].dt.day
df["percentage"] = np.random.randint(1,60, len(df))
```

Now I use `pivot_table` to obtain a `df` with a column per date

```
ddf = pd.pivot_table(df,
                     index="time",
                     columns="date",
                     values="percentage")
```

If we try to plot we obtain the fig you didn't like

```
ddf.plot(figsize=(16,6))\
   .legend(loc="upper left", bbox_to_anchor=(1,1));
```

But we can fix it via

```
ddf.interpolate()\
   .plot(figsize=(16,6))\
   .legend(loc="upper left", bbox_to_anchor=(1,1));
```

Comment: tnx! never heard of "interpolate" Superb!